# Where to get Docklets

Tags: docky

I am very new to ubuntu and feel a bit overwhelmed at times.  I downloaded docky because I think its handy but I only see a limited amount of docklets in the docky settings.  Trying to search and find an answer to this Ive noticed on other peoples screenshots that they have many docklets.  Is there another way to get these docklets besides from the docky settings menu?

Comment: read the docky docs http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=Adding/Removing_application_launchers,_folders_and_files

Answer (score 2):

Docky is included in the official Ubuntu repositories starting in Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx). To install Docky on Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx) or later:

```
  sudo apt-get install docky
```

There are two official Docky PPAs. One with our bleeding edge version built from Docky trunk and one including the latest build of the current Docky stable branch.

The Docky [Stable PPA](https://launchpad.net/~docky-core/+archive/stable) . Use this PPA for the current, stable version of Docky.

To use the Docky Stable PPA, for Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx) and later:

```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:docky-core/stable
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install docky
```

The Docky [Development PPA](https://launchpad.net/~docky-core/+archive/ppa) and typically lags behind the source by about a day. Use this PPA for the most current, updated version of Docky.

To use the Docky Development PPA, for Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx) and later:

```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:docky-core/ppa
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install docky
```

To update Docky, if you installed Docky as a package from either the official repositories or one of our PPAs, run:

```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you want docklets that are not found in docky settings, it means that these docklets are third party so you have to go to their website and download or googleit you'll find much more.